# Simple Dom Parser - stripping links and specific divs from the result

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, simpledom

I am trying to parse some content from a specific div and save it to an external file. Although this works, I couldn't manage to do the following

From the div with class `league_container`

1. remove all divs with the class `bar`
2. strip all links. (leave the text but remove `a` plus its attributes)

What I have so far is:

```
   <?php
    include( 'simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $html = file_get_html('https://some.domain.com/');

    $divContents = array();

    foreach ($html->find('div.league_container') as $div) 
    {
        $divContents[] = $div->outertext;
    }       


file_put_contents('parser/est-results.htm', implode(PHP_EOL, $divContents));
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `outertext =` :

```
$div->outertext = '';
$a->outertext = $a->text();
```

Comment: tanks for the reply, i am not sure how this code is going to select and remove the divs with class "bar"?

Comment: Just iterate `$html->find('.bar')`